# How to sort data in Qlist with QSortFilterProxyModel::sort

Tags: c++, qt

I have model QSortFilterProxyModel, and i have QList<Qt::CheckState> isSelected.

I want use QSortFilterProxyModel::sort. But when I sort my TableView data in isSelected do not sort.

How can I fix this?

Comment: please provide [mcve] of your attempt to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem this way

```
QModelIndex that = index(row, 0);
QModelIndex source = mapToSource(that);
bool currentValue = mProcessModel.isSelected.at(source.row());
```